# Is f(int const) better than f(int) for compiler optimization?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, constants, compiler-optimization

Consider the following two functions:

```
void f(int n);

void f(int const n);
```

From the perspective of compiler optimization, the latter seems better than the former.

However, from the perspective of the caller, `int const n` has *more useless information* and *more mental load* than `int n`.

**Which is the better practice?**

Comment: Caller doesn't have to see the `const`. You can put it into the implementation file, that's legal.

Comment: Are they two equivalent as per the C++ standard?

Comment: If you're asking whether you're allowed to have mismatch between the declaration and the definition in top-level parameter constness, yes.

Comment: I have many inline member functions, and I don't want to separate them into declarations and definitions. How about in this case?

Comment: @xmllmx Simplest possible code should be your goal 99% of the time. If you can prove that using an extra const means more optimisation and your program benefits from that optimisation then you might have a case, but not otherwise.

Comment: I'd first confirm that `const` actually affects optimization. If yes (and I think it does), it's then completely opinion-based (whether you want to pay the mental load price for potentially better performance). I personally wouldn't bother with `const` by default.

Comment: There is no difference between the two (whether in terms of performance, opportunities for compiler optimisation, or anything else).   If the function is declared (not defined) in one way, and defined in the other way, then the two match.

Comment: Interstingly, I got the same assembly with and without const: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s8ejMMf3P I wonder why.

Comment: [Does const'ing primitive types in function parameters result in a significant performance boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396756/does-consting-primitive-types-in-function-parameters-result-in-a-significant-pe) and [Passing arguments to functions with const parameters: is it faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291607/passing-arguments-to-functions-with-const-parameters-is-it-faster)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TLDR: In practice, there will be zero performance benefits from doing this.
Use const for clarity and readability, not performance.

As `const` on function parameters is not even part of the function signature,
both functions will have exactly the same calling convention, no matter your ABI. This means that there is zero benefit for callers.

Inside the function itself, `const` doesn't help the compiler much either.
Any compiler worth it's salt can figure out by itself whether you are modifying `n`.

It's possible to construct pathological cases, where the `const` *could* allow the compiler to assume certain things.
For example, that a nested function call, that we pass `n` as a (non const) pointer to, will not modify it.
This *could* allow the compiler to do better store -> load forwarding and avoid spilling to the stack. As it stands, compiler don't even seem to take advantage of that though (https://godbolt.org/z/jGsKo56aG).

Comment: *"compiler worth it's salt can figure out by itself whether you are modifying `n`"* What about passing it to an opaque function by const reference? If it's `const`, it can't be modified (or we get UB). If it's non-const, the callee can cast the constness away. In practice the compilers seem to assume that even a `const` local variable can be modified.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if you pass by value const doesn't matter anyway. For const reference it might matter, yes.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: that is the exact example I gave at the bottom. If you look at the godbolt link, you will see that the generated assembly is identical for both cases.

Comment: There's a tiny difference but yes, I started writing my comment before finishing reading the answer. :/

Comment: To make things even worse, const objects may be mutable. If you combine it with inheritance and virtuality then this means that compiler cannot even assume that const ref is really const. What a great language...

Comment: @freakish  And that's why we love it so